# Вопрос по циклу for

Tags: c++, c, циклы

Каким образом производится проверка на истинность j<=(i/j) , ведь по условию выходит, что j всегда будет больше. Например j=2  ; (i/j)=(2/2)=1 --->>>  Выходит 2<=1? Объясните.

```
int main ()
{ 
    int i , j ;
    for ( i= 2 ; i<1000 ; i++ )
    {
        for (j =2 ;j<=(i/j) ; j++)
            if (!(i%j)) break ;

        if(j > (i/j)) cout << i<< endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну возьмите 100 и 2 :) Правда, 2 < 100/2?

Это по сути проверка `j*j <= i`. Зачем ее написали именно в таком виде - с делением - непонятно...

Comment: Я понимаю, что тут ищутся простые числа. Если они делятся сами на себя и на единицу(а на единицу всегда все делится), то продолжать . Но каким образом происходит j<=(i/j) ? 2 ведь не меньше и не равен 1. Противоречие же получается.

Comment: Ваше решение несомненно подходит.. Но помогите все же разобраться с тем, как оно работает пошагово?

Comment: Почему условие 2<=1 или j*j<=i -->> 4<=2 воспринимается как верное?

Comment: Покажите мне, где оно верно?! http://ideone.com/Ul4IcY - вот, убедитесь сами, **какие** пары переменных проходят...

Comment: Почему j не увеличивается? 
Когда i = 4 , j = 2 , при j<=(i/j) >> 2<=(4/2) >> 2<=2 >> значит в for(int j = 2 ; j<=(i/j) ; j++)  сout << <<  J должно увеличиться на единицу, и вывод должен быть. 
Если же 2<=1  или подобное , то оно не выводится и не увеличивается , вот тут логично все. Именно поэтому мы и начинаем с 4 :2 ,а  не с 3: 2 , 2:2

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы хотите спросить... :( Хорошо, i = 4, j = 2. При этом `i%j == 0`, так что проходит команда `break`, выход из цикла. Что дальше? Что, по-вашему, должно увеличиваться?

Comment: j . В цикле for сказано, что он должен увеличиваться с каждой итерацией, но изменяется только i ,а j стоит на месте несколько раз подряд, даже при верном условии

Comment: Послушайте, возьмите лист бумаги и распишите, что и как происходит. `j` увеличивается во втором цикле - если, конечно, первая же проверка `if (!(i%j))` не оказывается истинной. Для четных чисел никакого увеличения `j` нет и быть не может. Для нечетных - может. например, при i=5. Сначала j = 2, затем j=3, но так как 3 > (5/3), происходит выход из цикла. Посмотрите тут сами - http://ideone.com/23x10o Для нечетных j увеличивается, что четко видно в строках "Leave loop for "

Comment: P.S. Простите уж, но больше я к этому не возвращаюсь - по-моему, все очевидно. Если что непонятно - пройдите в отладчике пошагово.

Comment: " j увеличивается во втором цикле - если, конечно, первая же проверка if (!(i%j)) не оказывается истинной." -Вот оно что. Увеличивается, если проверка не оказывается истинной. Все это очень странно выглядит.. Но спасибо. Теперь наконец понятно..

Comment: Там же `break` - ничего странного.